# where to modify x axis length. AKA I want to show future years in chart

Tags: d3.js

I'm working this chart:
https://dev-sandbox-is-web.pantheonsite.io/resource/the-value-of-volunteer-time/

The data is pulled from CSV. The chart is auto-scaling the years to only show even years. How can I control this so it either shows all the years or force the timeline to show 2018 despite not having data yet for that year?

I just need to know what parameter I need to modify and I can do the rest of the documentation.

Comment: If you could show us some code that would be super helpful. But you could try changing the x axis scale range to be `maxyear + some_factor` where some factor is enough to make it look ahead `x years.`

Comment: thanks for the reply. The JS for the chart is [here] (http://independentsector.org/wp-content/themes/independent-sector/js/vv/chart.js) .

(not sure why the link markdown isn't working)

Answer (score 0):

The changes you will want to make are here:

```
var xExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.year; });
var yExtent = d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.value; });
var x = d3.time.scale().domain(xExtent);
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain(yExtent);
```

Instead change your `xExtent = [d3.min(data, d=>d.year), d3.max(data, d=>d.year) + someFactor]` where some factor can be something that will add two years.

My suggestion is to add `2 * 3.154e+10` as `3.154e+10` is one year in milliseconds, which is probably what is used under the hood.

Another way to do this (kinda hard-coded) is to do `xExtent = [d3.min(data, d=>d.year), 2018]`, and make 2018 the max. This is of course less sustainable because the chart will not always show 2 extra years as your data becomes more current.

Comment: Thank you so much. I opted for the "hard-code" option since we have other charts we have to update code for annually anyway. Works great.

I actually could not get the first method to work. The chart would just explode to the distant future. I think the source data is not parsing as an actual year. So far as the chart knows, it's just integer... but I didn't make the original so I'm not sure.

Comment: @Ian Ahh nice, Ya if its taking a year then probably just needed to add 2 or something. If this helped if you could please mark as accepted that would be helpful.